# How to "force" a pull request from a specific commit?

Tags: git, version-control, git-push, pull-request, git-reset

The scenario is the following:

- We have around 10 commits that we want to revert from our master branch. They are causing some sort of issue and I need to revert to a specific commit `123abc`;

Some things we tried here:

- We created a new branch called `feature/something` in order to revert the commit and do a `pull request` to the master branch. However, VSTS is complainng that we don't have new changes.
- When we do `git reset --hard 123abc` into `master` branch, my local space is reverted to the given commit, that's OK so far. However, I don't have permission to ***force*** a push to the master branch.

So, my questions are:

- Regarding the 1st attempt, how to make git understand that I want to pull those changes to master branch and don't complain?
- Regarding the 2nd attempt, how to ***force*** a pull request from master branch from that given commit?

Thank you all!

Comment: Are you using `git request-pull` to make this pull request? If not, what are you using, and what is VSTS (which is not in your tags here)? (That last question is kind of a hint. I could *assume* it stands for Visual Studios Team Services, but I don't use Visual Studios so I can't really be sure, nor, unfortunately, help with whatever it is that Visual Studios itself does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make a branch to an old commit through pull request.

If you have not force push permission, you should revert changes on a new branch and create PR to merge the new branch into `master`, or you can ask the team project administrator to reset master branch to an old commit.

#### Option 1: revert the changes on `master` branch

Assume the commit history on master branch as below, and the commits `C1` to `C10` are the commits you want to revert:

```
…---A---C1---C2---…---C10   master
```

- If `master` branch has no branch policies, you can directly revert on `master` branch and push to remote.

  ```
  # On local master branch
  git revert C1^..
  git push origin master
  ```

  After revert the changes, the commit history on `master` branch should be:

  ```
  …---A---C1---C2---…---C10---C10'---C9'---…---C1'   master
  ```
- If `master` branch has branch policies, you can create a new branch (such as `feature/something` branch) from `master` branch, then revert commits on `feature/something` branch and create a PR to merge `feature/something` branch into `master`:

  ```
  # On local master branch
  git checkout -b feature/something
  git revert C1^..
  git push -u origin feature/something
  ```

  Then the commit history  will be:

  ```
  …---A---C1---C2---…---C10   master
                          \
                           C10'---C9'---…---C1'   fearure/something
  ```

  You can create a PR to merge `feature/something` into `master`. And it shouldn’t complain there hasn’t new changes unless you revert/merge on the opposite way.

#### Option 2: ask team project administrator to reset and force push to `master` branch

If there has no branch policies on `master` branch, you can ask team project administrator to reset `master` branch and then force push (as the 2nd attempt you tried). Or you can ask the administrator to allow you to force push.

Answer (score 0):

*Option 1: `revert`*

In the first attempt, it seems you want to add a commit to `master` to undo the changes from the 10 commits.  You're envisioning this as a merge between the current ip of `master`, and a commit before the 10 commits you want to undo.

Of course if this did what you're currently wanting, then that would mean that normal merges would be constantly undoing changes from one side of the merge or other - which is exactly what a merge is supposed to *not* do.

In git, the word for what you're trying to do is `revert`.  If you have

```
x -- x -- x -- A -- B -- ... -- I -- J -- o <--(master)
```

and you want to undo `A` thru `J`, you could say something like

```
git revert -n A^..J
```

(replacing `A` and `J` with ID's or other expressions that resolve to the corresponding commits; in this example one way to spell it out would be

```
git revert -n master~11..master^
```

remembering that the first expression would point to `A`'s *parent* rather than `A` itself).

This will update your index and working tree to undo the changes from the specified range of commits.  So then

```
git commit -m "Revert commits A through J"
```

If you don't want to have to explicitly commit, you can leave off the `-n` option, but then you'll get 10 new commits (one to undo each of the original commits).

The commits don't necessarily have to be sequential; you could name each commit individually instead of specifying a range.  And this should work regardless of the branch topology.  Do note that revert operations can conflict, and the more changes have occurred after a commit that you're reverting the more likely a conflict becomes.

As a special case, if the 10 commits make up all of a feature branch, as in

```
x -- x -- x -- x -- x -- x -- y --- M -- o <--(master)
           \                       /
            A -- B -- ... -- I -- J <--(feature_branch)
```

you could say

```
git revert -m1 M
```

(where `M` is again some expression like the commit ID of `M`, or `master^` in this example, etc.)

This means you want to apply the inverse of the changes `M` made over its 1st parent (`y`).  Be aware, though, that once you revert a merge you can't just redo the merge later (because from git's point of view, those changes are already merged in even though you happen to have later undone them).  You could later "revert the revert", or you could do a rebase to recreate the branch with new commits and re-merge from that.

*Option 2: rewrite history*

On the other hand, you could remove the original commits from the history of the `master` branch.  Your second attempt is one way to do that.  As you note, not every remote gives you the permission to do a force push - and for good reason (there are side effects).  Every method of rewriting history will ultimately require a force push, so if you don't have permission then this simply isn't an option.